# Make Horizontal ListView in Vertical Listview at a fragment of ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I want make a view as this picture: A viewpager have one page is a fragment, inside this fragment have a normal listview, and sometime have a special row that is a horizontal listview (not recycler view).

### [image]

How do I make as abover and prevent conflict when scroll hozirontal listview with viewpager ?

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods :

> public int getItemViewType(int position)
>
> public int getViewTypeCount()

if the type of item is  horizontal listview that you can return this special item view in getView(),like this [Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

Comment: This only method to make many type in listview, problem is how to scroll horizontal listview that is not conflict with viewpager

Comment: Override viewPager's and horizontal listView's  onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)  method

Comment: Could you give me a code to implement it ? because I try some solution with that and unsuccessful

Comment: horizontal listView's onInterceptTouchEvent() or  dispatchTouchEvent() add 'getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);' if you want more logic,you need more code